# What does the "by" argument in ffbase::as.character do?

Tags: r, character, optional-parameters, coercion, ffbase

In the post below,

[aggregation using ffdfdply function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951433/aggregation-using-ffdfdply-function-in-r)

There is a line like this.

```
splitby <- as.character(data$Date, by = 250000)
```

Just out of curiosity, I wonder what `by` argument means. It seems to be related to `ff` dataframe but I'm not sure. Google search and R documentation of `as.character` and `as.vector` provided no useful information.

I tried some examples but the codes below give the same results.

```
d <- seq.Date(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date()+10000, by = "day")
as.character(d, by=1)
as.character(d, by=10)
as.character(d, by=100)
```

If anybody could tell me what it is, I'd appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `as.character.ff` works using the default `as.character` internally, and in view of the fact that df vectors can be larger than RAM, the data needs to be processed in chunks. The partition into chunks is facilitated by the `chunk` function. In this case, the relevant method is `chunk.ff_vector`. By default, this will calculate the chunk size by dividing `getOption("ffbatchbytes")` by the record size. However, this behaviour can be overridden by supplying the chunk size using `by`.

In the example you give, the ff vector will be converted to `character` 250000 members at a time.

The end result will be the same for any `by` or without `by` at all. Larger values will lead to greater temporary use of RAM but potentially quicker operation.

Answer (score 1):

First, that function is `ffbase::as.character`, not plain old `base::as.character`

See http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/ffbase/docs/as.character.ff
which says

```
as.character((x, ...))

Arguments:
x: a ff vector
...: other parameters passed on to chunk
```

So the `by` argument is being passed through to some `chunk` function.
Then you need to figure out which package's `chunk` function is being used. Type `?chunk`, tell us which one, then go read its doc to see what its `by` argument does.

Comment: The `by` is being passed to ´chunk.default´, so the documentation for it in `?chunk` is as accurate as it gets: `by: increment of the sequence` (to be used as in `?seq`).

Comment: Then it's just being ignored. In R all unknown or unused args get ignored, silently. This might have been a cut-and-paste typo by the original poster, e.g. from copying a seq(...) command.

Comment: I don't think it is being ignored. Both `chunk.ff_vector` and `chunk.ffdf` capture `...` and pass it on to `chunk.default` via `do.call`. If `by` is specified, then `chunk.default` will use it (as the documentation suggests, in a similar way as `seq` uses it).

Comment: Ok, but I can't find a documentation page for `ffbase::chunk.default` , they could do with adding one...

Comment: The documentation for this function (`as.character.ff`) isn't particularly helpful in this regard. Neither your answer nor that of @smci really explain what the end result is of varying `by` in this case. To really understand what it was doing I had to look at the code for this function as well as the code for two methods of `chunk`!

Comment: @NickK yes, I couldn't find the source for `ffbase::chunk.default`, I've never used it and I wasn't going to install yet another package just to answer this question. Really someone needs to add the missing doc pages for that package. A common story in R packages... I did point the OP towards how to solve it for themselves.

Comment: @smci entirely agree that the problem is the documentation! The relevant function is in the `bit` package. The problem is that even with the documentation for that package, it's not clear what passing `by` to `chunk.ff_vector` does since it's not mentioned in the help page. Also `?chunk` doesn't give the full answer because it's the `ff_vector` method rather than `default` one that gets called (although that in turn calls `chunk.default`!)

Comment: `ffbase::chunk.default` does not exist because `chunk.default` is in `base`.

Comment: @SimonG no it's specifically not, that's what the OP's issue is here. They're in [`bit::chunk`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/bit/docs/chunk) and `bit::chunk.default`. Evidently `bit` package is a dependency of `ffbase` which gets imported. Like I said there is also a `base::chunk` and that is **not** what's getting called here.