# How to split/aggregate a large data frame (ffdf) by multiple columns?

Tags: r

`ffbase` provides the function `ffdfdply` to split and aggregate data rows. This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20954315/336311) explains how that can basically work. I still cannot figure out how to split by multiple columns.

My challange is that a split variable is required. This must be unique for each combination of the two variables, I'd like to split by. Still, in my 4-column data frame (about 50M rows), it would require a lot of memory, if creating a character vector by `paste()`.

This is where I got stuck...

```
require("ff")
require("ffbase")
load.ffdf(dir="ffdf.shares.02")

# Aggregation by articleID/measure
levels(ffshares$measure) #  "comments", "likes", "shares", "totals", "tw"
splitBy = paste(as.character(ffshares$articleID), ffshares$measure, sep="")

tmp = ffdfdply(fftest, split=splitBy, FUN=function(x) {
  return(list(
    "articleID" = x[1,"articleID"],
    "measure" = x[1,"measure"],
    # I need vectors for each entry
    "sx" = unlist(x$value), 
    "st" = unlist(x$time)
  ))
}
)
```

Of course, I could use shorter levels for `ffshares$measure` or simply use the numeric codes, but this still won't solve the underlying problem that `splitBy` grows enormously large.

**Sample Data**

```
    articleID  measure                time value
100        41   shares 2015-01-03 23:20:34     4
101        41       tw 2015-01-03 23:30:30    24
102        41   totals 2015-01-03 23:30:38     6
103        41    likes 2015-01-03 23:30:38     2
104        41 comments 2015-01-03 23:30:38     0
105        41   shares 2015-01-03 23:30:38     4
106        41       tw 2015-01-03 23:40:24    24
107        41   totals 2015-01-03 23:40:35     6
108        41    likes 2015-01-03 23:40:35     2
...
1000       42   shares 2015-01-04 20:10:50     0
1001       42       tw 2015-01-04 21:10:45    24
1002       42   totals 2015-01-04 21:10:35     0
1003       42    likes 2015-01-04 21:10:35     0
1004       42 comments 2015-01-04 21:10:35     0
1005       42   shares 2015-01-04 21:10:35     0
1006       42       tw 2015-01-04 22:10:45    24
1007       42   totals 2015-01-04 22:10:43     0
1008       42    likes 2015-01-04 22:10:43     0
...
```

Comment: Can you provide example data?

Comment: You're welcome. It's very simple data - just of alot of it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Use this, this makes sure your data does not get into RAM completely but only in chunks of 100000 records
ffshares$splitBy <- with(ffshares[c("articleID", "measure")], paste(articleID, measure, sep=""), 
                         by = 100000)
length(levels(ffshares$splitBy)) ## how many levels are in there - don't know from your question

tmp <- ffdfdply(ffshares, split=ffshares$splitBy, FUN=function(x) {
  ## In x you are getting a data.frame in RAM with all records of possibly several articleID/measure combinations
  ## You should write a function which returns a data.frame. E.g. the following returns the mean value by articleID/measure and the first and last timepoint
  x <- data.table::setDT(x)
  xagg <- x[, list(value = mean(value), 
                   first.timepoint = min(time),
                   last.timepoint = max(time)), by = list(articleID, measure)]
  ## the function should return a data frame as indicated in the help of ffdfdply, not a list
  setDF(xagg)
})
## tmp is an ffdf
```

Comment: Huh, the paste() and ffdfdply() commands both kept R working a while. May be caused by the 400k split-levels in my data. Still, your solution did the trick. Thanks a lot!